# UIImageView not positioned correctly inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've got scrollview in scrollview (one for paging and one for zooming). The outer container only occupies part of the screen. The inner scrollviews are created programatically with frame matching the outer frame but with origin (0, page * width_of_outer). The problem is that when the screen is loaded the inner scrollview doesn't appear at y = 0 but is offset by what seems to be y of the outer frame. As soon as I touch something inside the inner scrollview is moved to correct position occupying the whole outer scrollview. I can't figure why... The frames of inners are correct with y = 0. All are added as subview of outer. Any ideas?

EDIT:
My inner is created

```
    CGRect frame = self.frame; // or bounds - doesn't make any difference
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

    // this will cause calling [UIScrollView initWithFrame: frame];        
    MyScrollView *scrollView = [[MyScrollView alloc] initWithPage:page andFrame:frame];

    [self addSubview: scrollView];
```

Comment: Can you show the internal scroll view frame creation code?

Comment: When are you running the above code? `viewDidLoad`, `viewdidlayoutsubviews`, etc?

Comment: Is `self` in this fragment the outer scroll view?

Comment: Neal - it's in separate method called from parent (so I guess it's after all the normal ones). Alexander: yes, self is the outer scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `inner.frane = outter.bounds;`.

Comment: Thanks but this makes no difference